# Memory test results

Tags: windows-vista

Before Windows started I ran the Windows Memory Test.

After that the computer automatically restarted before I could see the results of the test.

How can I pull up the results of the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can find the log.
I am assuming the computer had a Windows OS in it.

Here is how you find it.
Go to Event Log use the "System" log.

Search for this:
[image]